# Doxygen generation from DSL Language

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, doxygen

I know that the same question has been asked already but still i didn't get any clear idea from that page.

Basically i have my own DSL(Domain specific language) in Eclipse IDE, out of that i want to generate Doxygen and it should show docs when i mouse over in IDE on DSL parameters(Similar to JavaDoc. For example: System.out.println("Sample") when i mouse over on println word then it will show javadoc).

First please confirm if i convert my DSL language to C then it will generate Doxygen documents. Then after that how will i get javadoc when i mouse over.

Many thanks in Advance.